# Jupyter lab sidebar damages after installing an extension

Tags: table-of-contents, extension, jupyter

I'm trying to install TOC extension for Jupyter lab.
The issue is the same for both ways of installation:
from the command window or from the extension manager.

1. I'm installing an extension using the command:

   ```
   jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/toc
   ```
2. I have to build jupyter lab using:

   ```
   jupyter lab build
   ```
3. Icons from sidebar disappearing like in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856540/sidebar-disappearing-jupyter-lab).
   Here is the screen: [image: [the screen][2].]

And I cannot return to normal view unless I reinstall Anaconda.
What can I do for correct work?  How can I return to correct build of Jupyter Lab?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest upgrading to the latest version of Jupyterlab. I was having a similar error as mentioned here https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/7158 and the problem has disappeared after I upgrade from 1.0.2 (as per anaconda package) to 1.1.2.

Good luck and I hope this will solve your issue.